# Query AD using PowerShell to match binary data

Tags: powershell, active-directory, binary-data

I am a PowerShell newbie, in fact very, very newbie. I have a task I cannot perform otherwise than using PowerShell (I don't want to justify why, by trust me on this I don't want to enter into discussions about other ways around).

So here is my problem. I need to query Active Directory for a matching record seeking the equality for a 16 bytes binary field (called netbootGUID in our installation). The goal is to make sure no other records exists with the same netbootGUID before adding a new record (no, they cannot enforce the policy at the database level and I have no control on this from my side of the wall).

What I am doing as a test to evolve toward a final solution, I am getting a record, pick its netbootGUID and then query back AD with the netbootGUID I just picked in order to test a positive answer.

Here is a code snippet intended to do just that:

```
$value = Get-ADComputer -Server $myADserver -SearchBase "CN=Computers,$baseDN" -Filter 'Name -eq "an_existing_computer"' -Credential $credentials -Properties netbootGUID
$guid = $value.netbootGUID
Get-ADComputer -Server $myADserver -SearchBase "CN=Computers,$baseDN" -Filter "netbootGUID -eq $guid" -Credential $credentials -Properties Name
```

Instead of getting a value when I perform the search on the netbootGUID value I got earlier, I am getting an error message:

```
Get-ADComputer : Erreur lors de l’analyse de la requête: «netbootGUID -eq 198 132 111 6 121 119 69 126 168 146 101 129 136 20 157 221» Message d’erreur: «syntax error» à la position: «21».
Au caractère C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tests PowerShell\netbootGUID_AD_Caisses.ps1:42 : 1
+ Get-ADComputer -Server $serveurAD -SearchBase "CN=Computers,$baseDN" -Filter "ne ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingExeption,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

I apologize for the French error message I don't know how to switch to English.

It seems to say the 16 bytes binary value passed as $guid is interpreted as a string instead of an array or something like that. I probably need to "cast" something or make the type explicit.

Anyone can help me with this one?

Comment: Get all the `netbootGUID`s and `Group-Object` them and see if there are any that count more than once. `Get-ADComputer -Server $myADserver -SearchBase "CN=Computers,$baseDN" -Properties netbootGuid | Group-Object -property netbootGuid | Where-Object -Property Count -gt 1` or similar.

Comment: In fact, what I will need instead is to check if the netbootGUID to add already exists. So, I must never have anything counting more than once. I must not add something and check afterward neither.
In summary, if I am getting all the netbootGUID at once, I need to check if the provided one is already a member of the collection.
The problem with this approach is I have to iteratively add computers and I will need to make this every time I add a new computer. Rebuilding the Group-Object each time which can become very large as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a raw LDAP query filter for this. Two things to keep in mind when using LDAP for binary data search:

1. Binary filters must match the exact value (no partial or wildcard searching)
2. Each byte needs to be converted to hexadecimal and prefixed with `\`

With this in mind, we'll need a filter looking somethind like this:

```
(netboodGUID=\C6\84\6F\06\79\77\45\7E\A8\92\65\81\88\14\9D\DD)
```

Starting from a byte array, you could do something like this:

```bsh
$guidBinaryString = @($guid|ForEach-Object { '\{0:X2}' -f $_ }) -join ''
$LDAPFilter = "(netboodGUID=$guidBinaryString)"

Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter -Server $myADserver -SearchBase "CN=Computers,$baseDN" -Credential $credentials -Properties Name
```